# How will we implement the security in the SharePoint hosted app which deployed on SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, security, sharepoint-hosted-app

In our project, users will allow to upload the document only through the app and will have also provided links in apps to directly download the file

e.g :

https://zzzz.sharepoint.com/sites/zzz/DMSDocument/1027/091CHEN030006931456/test.doc.

But they can't directly upload any document through below URL

https://zzzz.sharepoint.com/sites/zzz/DMSDocument/Forms/AllItems.aspx

I have set the custom permission level in which the following roles are unchecked

- View Application Pages( View forms, views and application pages,Enumerated lists)

In this way, I can stop user to directly to go `ALLitems.aspx` page, but he can't download the document by the above-mentioned link.

How can achieve this security in a better way?

Comment: Using SPD using All Files navigation delete those aspx pages from the Forms folder.